# Где находится файл с таблицами entity framework после запуска

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Использую entity framework для работы с БД, использую MS SQL Server. Все работает, после добавления записей могу достать их и вывести в консоль, но мне бы хотелось увидеть саму таблицу и как выглядит созданный файл. Я предполагаю он создается, так как я могу запустить .exe и все работает. Закидывал файлы из дебага в SSMS, но таблицы так и не увидел, только какую-то структуру файла. Подскажите с помощью чего я могу это сделать.

Comment: Смотрите строку подключения в вашем приложении, туда же подключайтесь через ssms

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Первый раз в БД полез.